# repo installation problem on windows

Tags: android

helllo,

I want to download whole android plateform code. I am able to use GIT in my windows pc but i am not getting any idea how to install Repo. if some one can help me with it then it would be really helpful to me.

Comment: ask programming related questions over here

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide further details about your progress using it? What have you tried etc...

My initial thought is that since you are on windows you don't have python installed which is what repo actually is; a python script.

Comment: Hi yeol, Thanks for your reply. So according to you i should install python first ?

Comment: @kartik trivedi - check to make sure python isn't already installed, if it is not then install it, you need it to run the repo script